# Wronskian evaluated at different points, second order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly independent solutions to:

$e^{x}y" + e^{x}($$a$ cos$x + 2x + b)y' + xy = 0$
.

What are all possible constants a, b such that the Wronskian for this equation, $W(y_1,y_2)(t)$, satisfies
$W(y_1,y_2)(0) = W(y_1,y_2)(\pi) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Use [Abel's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_identity#Statement). ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$